If convex functions $f_n$ converges against a convex function $f$, do the level sets converge in the Lipschitz sense?
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a convex bounded domain.
Suppose that $f_n : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a sequence of bounded convex functions that converges to some bounded convex function $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ uniformly.
We introduce the level sets
$$
L(c) = \{ x \in \Omega : f(x) = c \},
\qquad 
L_n(c) = \{ x \in \Omega : f_n(x) = c \}
$$
for each $c \in \mathbb R$.
Do the level sets converge in the Lipschitz sense? That means:
Given $c \in \mathbb R$ with $\min(f) < c < \max(f)$, we want that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $N$ large enough such that for all $n \geq N$ there exists a homeomorphism
$$
g_n : L(c) \rightarrow L_n(c)
$$
that satisfies the bi-Lipschitz condition
$$
\operatorname{Lip}(g_n) \leq 1 + \epsilon, \qquad \operatorname{Lip}(g_n^{-1}) \leq 1 + \epsilon.
$$
I am excluding the minimum and maximum as possible level sets since the statement might not hold for those. Can we set up
